# Addition of two 8-bits number in 8086 using MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, microprocessors, emu8086

This is the code that I have written in 8086 using MASM. The code is for simple addition of two 8-bit numbers (no need to worry about carry). I gave for input to the following program, two numbers: 31h and 16h . The output should have been 47h but it is giving me the output as 'w'. The code works fine if I take numbers whose some does not exceed 9, can someone please point out my mistake here?

CODE:

```
data segment
   n1 db 31h
   n2 db 16h
data ends

code segment
 assume cs:code, ds:data
  start:

   mov ax,data
   mov ds,ax

   mov al,n1
   mov bl,n2
   add al,bl

   add al,30h
   mov dl,al

   mov ah,02h
   int 21h

   mov ah,4ch
   int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Comment: see the multi-digit numbers FAQ in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  It has some links to integer->string examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add the two constants you wanted, you `add al,30h`, giving you a value of `77h`.  This is the ASCII code for `w`, which you then print as an ASCII character rather than a number.

Comment: But if I remove the line `add al,30h` from the code, then no output is printed. Then how can I print that output?

Comment: Convert your result byte into two hex digits. Unpacked BCD arithmetic might help, or if there's a library function you can call, use that.

Comment: What you were trying to do is add the ASCII value of `'0'` to your byte.  You actually want to split the byte into two *nibbles*, add `'0'` (`30h`) if the nibble is less than 10, or add `'A'-10` (`37h`) if the nibble is 10 or greater.

Comment: Do that for both nibbles, and you get the ASCII code for `'0'`–`'9'` or `'A'`–`'F'`. But just adding `30h` only works for numbers less than 10 (`Ah`).